# Finding frequency of each item in a column using shell

Tags: shell

I'm quite inexperienced with shell/ mac terminal so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have a very large set of data with a tab delimiter. Here is an example of what the code looks like.

```
0001    User1    Tweet1
0002    User2    Tweet2
0003    User3    Tweet3
0004    User2    Tweet4
0005    User2    Tweet5
```

I've been trying export as a csv a list of each unique user and how many times they appear/make a tweet.

Here's my current attempt at the code:

```
cut -f 2 Twitter_Data_1 |sort | uniq -c | wc -l > TweetFreq.csv
```

Ideally I wish to export a csv that look like:

```
User1    1
User2    3
User3    1
```

Comment: you're already doing the counting with `uniq`. What is the purpose of `wc`?

Comment: good point but even after I remove it I'm only getting 1 output rather than a whole column

Comment: Update your question to show your current code and the output

Comment: Tried it again and seems to have worked. Cause the files so massive It only loaded partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F '\t' '{ print $2 }' tweet | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
  1 User1
  3 User2
  1 User3
```

Comment: As my 3rd column is not as uniform as my example how can I replace the word tweet?

Comment: `tweet` is the file name, in your case, it should be `Twitter_Data_1`

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest but it works

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir tmptweet # Creation of the temp directory
while read line; do
user=`echo $line | cut -d " " -f 2` # we access the username
echo $line >> tmptweet/$user # add a line to the selected user's counter
done < Twitter_Data_1

for file in tmptweet/*; do
i=`cat $file | wc -l` # we check the lines for each user ...
echo "${file##*/} $i" >> TweetFreq.csv # ... and put this into the final file
done
rm -rf tmptweet # remove of the temp directory
```

A temporary directory with temporary files are used to stores values, easier than juggling with `Array`.

Each line of your Twitter_Data_1 is inserted into a file named after the username, then one counts the number of line in each of those files to create the `TweetFreq.csv` file

**Test :**

```
Will /home/will # ls
script.sh     Twitter_Data_1
Will /home/will # ./script.sh
Will /home/will # ls
script.sh     Twitter_Data_1     TweetFreq.csv
Will /home/will # cat TweetFreq.csv
User1        1
User2        3
User3        1
Will /home/will #
```

Comment: Running the code now, Its taking a long time. Massive amount of data and its a mac... will keep you posted

Comment: You can check files are being created in `tmptweet` using `cd`and also use `tail -f TweetFreq.csv` to see the in-live feeding in the second part :-)

Comment: The tweetfreq.cv wasn't being created for me so i stopped the code

Comment: It will be created at the end of the script, this is why. How many entries has your `witter_Data_1` file ?

Comment: like over 10,000 is there any way to only do the head to test it?

Comment: You can take the first 500 lines of your file to test it and it suits what you need then run it again on the main file ? I've updated my code with comment btw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157137/discussion-between-will-and-liam).